# The curve $r = ae^{\theta \cot \alpha}$ cuts any radius vector in consecutive points $P_1$, $P_2$...., then prove given relation

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates, curvature

The curve $r = ae^{\theta \cot \alpha}$ cuts any radius vector in consecutive points $P_1, P_2,...,P_n, P_{n+1},...$.If $\rho_n$ denotes the radius of curvature at $P_n$, prove that $\frac{1}{m-n}\log\bigg(\frac{\rho_m}{\rho_n}\bigg)$ is a constant for all integral values of $m, n$.

Now, my attempt goes like this, I know this is the polar form of a curve, and so we can write the radius of curvature at any $\theta$ to be

$$\rho = \frac{[r_1^2+r^2]^{3/2}}{r^2+2r_1^2-rr_2}$$

where $r_1 = \frac{dr}{d\theta}$, $r_2 = \frac{d^2r}{d\theta^2}$

But then, what are the expressions for $\rho_m, \rho_n$? The above relation would give me the radius of curvature at any $\theta$ in terms of $a, \alpha, \theta$, but how do I proceed to prove the given expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step, you can easily show that $\rho=cr$, where $c$ is a constant (it just depends on $\alpha$). Then what you need to do is to calculate the intersections of the curve with a given radius vector. What's a radius vector? It's a straight line that has the origin at one end, and goes to infinity in the other direction. You can describe this as all the $(x,y)$ pairs such that $$\theta =\mathrm{atan2}(y,x)$$ The intersections of the original curve with this radius vector are at $$r_n=ae^{(\theta+(n-1)2\pi)\cot\alpha}$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Could you explain a bit about how you got the expression for $r_n$? I think once I get that, the problem should be easy to get from there on.

Comment: Also, yes, I've been able to prove that $\rho = cr$, that was just a bit of differentiation and algebraic manipulation

Comment: The expression for $r_n$ is just $r(\theta)$, where I plug in $\theta$, $\theta+2\pi$, $\theta+4\pi$, ... Why can I do that? Because $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$ have a period of $2\pi$. So in polar coordinates $(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$ is at the same position as  $(r\cos(\theta+2n\pi), r\sin(\theta+2n\pi))$

Comment: But why is that the points of intersections of the original curve with the radius vector? That is kinda what I'm having a bit of trouble getting at

Comment: The radius vector in Cartesian coordinates is just $y=mx$. If the point is on the curve, $x=r(\theta)\cos\theta$ and $y=r(\theta)\sin\theta$. At the intersection:$$r(\theta)\sin\theta=m r(\theta)\cos\theta$$If $r(\theta)$ is not zero, you can divide both sides by it, and get $$m=\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}=\tan\theta$$ You can find $\theta$ from this equation, plug it into the equation of the curve, and get the intersection point. But note again about the periodicity of $\sin$ and $\cos$. If $\theta$ is a solution, then so is $\theta+2n\pi$. But $r(\theta+2n\pi)$ is different.

Comment: Ah now I get that. So I have a relation that $\rho = cr$ and I also have $r_n, r_m$
Now all I need to do from what I understand is $\frac{\rho_m}{\rho_n} = \frac{cr_m}{cr_n}$ and go from there on, right?

Comment: Correct. All you need is to take the logarithm of a ratio of exponentials.